# Running script on output files

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to run script on output files that can be further used as input files for gaussian.
I wanted to know what are the commands used in Linux to run the script on .log files and .HSCP1 files.

Many thanks,
Regards,

Comment: What do you mean "What are the commands used to run the script on .log files and .hscp1 files" How would we know how your scripts work? I guess the best answer here is:  "It depends on how your script works".

Comment: I have a script file and I wanted to run this script on a .log file. What syntax/ commands should be use in Linux terminal.

Comment: You have a script. Great. This is like saying "I have an application, how do I import a picture into it". "I go to a certain website. How do I sign into it?" "I have a car what kind of oil does it take". "I have a pet what kind of food should I give it". The only answer is.. "It depends". If the script isn't large, perhaps you could share the code here and we could maybe backwards engineer it to help out how to feed it log files. We are definitely going to need more info to help though.

Answer (score 0):

The generic syntax of passing an argument to a script in linux, assuming your script is named `script.sh` and your target file is named `arg.log`, would be

```
script.sh arg.log
```

This assigns the name `arg.log` to `$1` inside the environment of the executing copy of `script.sh`. If you don't then do something with that, it won't matter.

You might also have your script read its stdin like this:

```
script.sh < arg.log
```

which will put the contents os `arg.log` on `script.sh`'s stdin, but unless it reads them accordingly, it won't matter.

Of course, both these assume `script.sh` is in your `$PATH`; otherwise you will need to apply a path for the OS, such as `/path/to/dir/with/script.sh` or (if you are in the same directory) `./script.sh`.

If what you are asking is how to get a lorge number of files assigned as arguments, you could pass wildcards - for the first example above, that could be done as

```
./script.sh /path/to/*.log /also/to/other.*
```

or you could use `find`, maybe with `xargs` like so -

```
find /path/to/files/ -name *.log | xargs /path/of/script.sh
```

which will call the script over and over.

I hope one of these helps, but you really must provide more context for what you are doing and how.